# create a manual configuration.xml file for a POS Printer using TCP/IP

Tags: c#, xml, printing, tcp

I have 2 Epson TM-T81 Thermal printers, 1 USB, 1 Ethernet port. Until now I have been using a single printer at a time.

I have built a c# code which prints to a particular printer. Now I want to have 2 printers associated with my program. For that I found out that I need to adjust the configuration.xml at my location:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Point Of Service\Configuration\configuration.xml

I now what changes I need to do to get a USB printer configured.
But my Ethernet printer in going to be connected directly with my wireless router, which has been installed, but without the configuration.xml being updated.

Here's my c# code

```
    <code>
     try
     {
        //Create PosExplorer
        PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();

        DeviceInfo deviceInfo = null;

        String strLogicalName="EpsonSale";
        try
        {
            deviceInfo = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, strLogicalName);
            m_Printer = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //ChangeButtonStatus();
            return;
        }

        //Register OutputCompleteEventHandler.
        AddOutputComplete(m_Printer);

        //Open the device
        m_Printer.Open();

        try
        {
            //Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            //Then the device is disable from other application.
            m_Printer.Claim(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Printer claimed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printer Not claimed");
        }

        //Enable the device.
        m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = true;

        //<<<step3>>>--Start
        //Output by the high quality mode
        m_Printer.RecLetterQuality = true;
       }
       catch(Exception){ Console.WriteLine("Printer Initialization failed.");}
```

My configuration.xml file containing the service objects:

```
 <code>
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <PointOfServiceConfig Version="1.0">
 <ServiceObject Type="PosPrinter" Name="TM-T81_203">
 <Device HardwarePath="ESDPRT001">
  <LogicalName Name="EpsonSale" />
  <Property Name="AsyncProcessingSize" Value="2" />
  <Property Name="AutoPowerOff" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="ConfigurationFile" Value="epson/xml/Setting/TM-T81_203Setting.xml" />
  <Property Name="Custom1Color" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="Cutter" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="DefaultCodePage" Value="997" />
  <Property Name="DefaultSlpClampTime" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="DeviceDesc" Value="EPSON TM-T81 POSPrinter" />
  <Property Name="DirectIOEventTimeout" Value="5000" />
  <Property Name="epson.trace.file" Value="trace.log" />
  <Property Name="epson.trace.max.size" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="epson.tracing" Value="false" />
  <Property Name="EPurasSupport" Value="TRUE" />
  <Property Name="FirmLogFileName" Value="Firmware.log" />
  <Property Name="FirmLogFileSize" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="FirmNotifyAllProgressEvents" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="FirmProgressRange" Value="10" />
  <Property Name="FirmRecordLog" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="Halftone" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="InitializeResponseTimeout" Value="5000" />
  <Property Name="InitializeThreadTime" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="InputBufferSize" Value="4096" />
  <Property Name="InputTimeout" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="KanjiTwoWaysPrint" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="LogicalName" Value="EpsonSale" />
  <Property Name="LogicalPortInterfaceName" Value="EPuras" />
  <Property Name="LogicalPortName" Value="pipe://TM/ESDPRT001" />
  <Property Name="LogObject" Value="" />
  <Property Name="MemorySwitch" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="NVRAMControlLevel" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="OfflineCount" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="OfflineRetryIntervalTime" Value="100" />
  <Property Name="OutputBufferSize" Value="32768" />
  <Property Name="OutputCompleteType" Value="2" />
  <Property Name="OutputErrorOption" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="OutputTimeout" Value="2000" />
  <Property Name="PageModeExt" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="Peeler" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="PhysicalDevice" Value="TM-T81_203" />
  <Property Name="PhysicalPrinterName" Value="TM-T81_203" />
  <Property Name="PortInterfaceName" Value="USB" />
  <Property Name="PortName" Value="ESDPRT001" />
  <Property Name="PortType" Value="3" />
  <Property Name="PrinterTransmitTimeout" Value="30000" />
  <Property Name="QueuingOfflineTimeout" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="ReadThreadInterval" Value="-1" />
  <Property Name="RecCharactersPerLine" Value="48" />
  <Property Name="ReceiveRetryTime" Value="25" />
  <Property Name="ReceiveTimeout" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="RecLineSpacing" Value="30" />
  <Property Name="RecMoreColumns" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="RecNearEndSensor" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="RecPaperType" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SlpMoreColumns" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SlpReverseEject" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="Stamp" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="StatusThreadInterval" Value="500" />
  <Property Name="SupportFirmware" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SupportStatistics" Value="1" />
  <Property Name="TcpPort" Value="9100" />
  <Property Name="TransmitRetryTime" Value="100" />
  <Property Name="TransmitTimeout" Value="5000" />
  <Property Name="TwoByteCharacter" Value="5" />
  <Property Name="TwoColor" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="U375Compatible" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="UdpPort" Value="3289" />
  <Property Name="UdpReceiveTimeout" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="UdpRetryCount" Value="2" />
  <Property Name="UdpRetryIntervalTime" Value="50" />
  <Property Name="UdpTransmitTimeout" Value="1000" />
  <Property Name="Upos.Spec_c" Value="false" />
  <Property Name="Upos.USB_Serial" Value="false" />
  <Property Name="UsedInterCharacterSet" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="UsedNVRAM" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="UsedPeeler" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="WriteThreadInterval" Value="-1" />
  </Device>
  </ServiceObject> 
  </PointOfServiceConfig>
  </code>
```

This printer gets claimed correctly for the USB one, but how do I add a service object for my TCP/IP port printer? I read somewhere that I can directly add a serviceObject to this file, but what will be my properties? Also I am using TCP/IP port and not a 'ESDPRT10xx' port.
I even tried a program by Sean Liming - SOMgr.exe for creating Service Objects, but could not find it useful.
I am not able to locate my Epson printer using `posExplorer.GetDevice()`

Also, Sorry if I have made any code formatting errors for this post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you. For my case, I am using JavaPOS instead of C# and I manage to print to my Epson TMU220 with Ethernet I/F card. Take a look at my xml configuration file below.

```
<JposEntry logicalName="EpsonTMU220BEthernet">
    <creation factoryClass="jp.co.epson.uposcommon.util.EpsonJposServiceInstanceFactory" 
              serviceClass="jp.co.epson.upos.pntr.U220BService"/>
    <vendor name="SEIKO EPSON" url="http://www.epson.com"/>
    <jpos category="POSPrinter" version="1.11"/>
    <product description="EPSON TM-U220B Printer Device Service" 
             name="EPSON Services for JavaPOS(TM) Standard" 
             url="http://www.epson.com"/>

    <!--Other non JavaPOS required property 
    (mostly vendor properties and bus specific properties i.e. RS232 )-->
    <prop name="Halftone" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PhysicalPrinterName" type="String" value="TM-U220B"/>
    <prop name="NVRAMControlLevel" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="Stamp" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="OutputCompleteType" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="StatusThreadInterval" type="String" value="500"/>
    <prop name="OutputTimeout" type="String" value="2000"/>
    <prop name="PortType" type="String" value="3"/>
    <prop name="OutputBufferSize" type="String" value="32768"/>
    <prop name="UsedNVRAM" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="FirmRecordLog" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="UdpRetryIntervalTime" type="String" value="50"/>
    <prop name="ReceiveTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="SlpReverseEject" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="OfflineRetryIntervalTime" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="PortName" type="String" value="192.168.12.192"/>
    <prop name="Upos.USB_Serial" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="DefaultSlpClampTime" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="epson.trace.file" type="String" value="trace.log"/>
    <prop name="AsyncProcessingSize" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="KanjiTwoWaysPrint" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="PulseStep" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="PortInterfaceName" type="String" value="Ethernet"/>
    <prop name="U375Compatible" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="preCutterFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="epson.tracing" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="epson.trace.max.size" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="RecPaperSize" type="String" value="76"/>
    <prop name="DeviceDesc" type="String" 
          value="EPSON TM-U220B POSPrinter"/>
    <prop name="PageModeExt" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SupportStatistics" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="FirmProgressRange" type="String" value="10"/>
    <prop name="OutputErrorOption" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="UdpReceiveTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="SupportFirmware" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="DeviceID" type="String" value="13"/>
    <prop name="InputTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="AutoPowerOff" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="SlpMoreColumns" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecPaperType" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="MemorySwitch" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="ReadThreadInterval" type="String" value="-1"/>
    <prop name="QueuingOfflineTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="InitializeThreadTime" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="TwoColor" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="TwoByteCharacter" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="UdpTransmitTimeout" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="FirmLogFileSize" type="String" value="1000"/>
    <prop name="Peeler" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="ConfigurationFile" type="String" 
          value="epson/xml/Setting/TM-U220BSetting.xml"/>
    <prop name="Custom1Color" type="String" value="0xFF0000"/>
    <prop name="preEndorseFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="Upos.Spec_c" type="String" value="false"/>
    <prop name="UdpRetryCount" type="String" value="2"/>
    <prop name="FirmNotifyAllProgressEvents" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InitializeResponseTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
    <prop name="ReceiveRetryTime" type="String" value="25"/>
    <prop name="PrinterTransmitTimeout" type="String" value="30000"/>
    <prop name="RecMoreColumns" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="UsedInterCharacterSet" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="TcpPort" type="String" value="9100"/>
    <prop name="WriteThreadInterval" type="String" value="-1"/>
    <prop name="UdpPort" type="String" value="3289"/>
    <prop name="preORCBFunction" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="RecNearEndSensor" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="LogObject" type="String" value=""/>
    <prop name="Cutter" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="PhysicalDevice" type="String" value="TM-U220B"/>
    <prop name="FirmLogFileName" type="String" value="Firmware.log"/>
    <prop name="UsedPeeler" type="String" value="0"/>
    <prop name="InputBufferSize" type="String" value="4096"/>
    <prop name="TransmitTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
    <prop name="EPurasSupport" type="String" value="TRUE"/>
    <prop name="OfflineCount" type="String" value="1"/>
    <prop name="TransmitRetryTime" type="String" value="100"/>
    <prop name="DirectIOEventTimeout" type="String" value="5000"/>
</JposEntry>
```

I believe that there are some values you will need to change to make it work such as: prop name="PortName" change to the 'printer IP address' instead of 'ESDPRT001'. Happy Working!

Comment: I had tried changing the PortName to the IP address, but it did not work, maybe some more changes are required.
Thanks for your xml, I'll cross check with mine, for something I might have missed out.

BTW is your printer directly/physically connected with your computer or passing through another router?